# Java | Memory Leak issue due to sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl

Tags: java, ssl, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, java-memory-leaks

In our application we are using Spring Framework v2.3.3.RELEASE. The application acts as a GRPC Server and responds to GRPC Requests sent from another application (It's micro-service architecture).

During our Performance Testing, we observed very high Memory Consumption in our app. On Analysing, found out that Old Generation was filling up very fast. Minor GC was not clearing up space.
[GC Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xhDA.png)

On taking Heap Dump, we found that the issue was with **sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl**
[Heap Dump Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWI6y.png)
[Incoming References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brXXE.jpg)

We are not using this Class from our side in the code. How can we find from where it is being referenced??

How can we get rid of this memory issue... if anyone else has faced this?

**Open JDK Version:** 1.8.0_262

**Java Options:** -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M -Xmx6144m -Xms6144m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseStringCache -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC

Comment: Did you find the cause of the memory consumption?